# HikariCP and maxLifetime

Tags: java, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I moved my project to [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). Everything is going fine so far, but with one setting I'm having trouble.

It's the `.setMaxLifetime(30*1000)` setting in HikariConfig object. I get this warning

```
WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maxLifetime is less than 120000ms, using default 1800000ms.
```

I know that they recommend not setting is that low as I am trying to. But Unfortunately due to circumstances that I can not change, every TCP connection that is open longer than 50 secods will be terminated in our production environment.

Comment: You will need to open an enhancement request for this.  As a temporary workaround, it is a hack but you can change the ``maxLifetime`` after the pool has started via JMX without an enforcement check.  See this wiki page for programmatic access: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JMX-Monitoring

Comment: Oh did not think about setting it through JMX, will try it. And submitted a feature request, wonder what they'll say

Answer (score 11):

i don't know your `HikariCP` Version, but in the version 2.2.4 you will find the reason why it will throw the above warning.
`HikariConfig.class` (in the `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig`):

```
 private void More ...validateNumerics()
  {
     Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

     if (connectionTimeout == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        logger.warn("No connection wait timeout is set, this might cause an infinite wait.");
     }

     if (minIdle < 0 || minIdle > maxPoolSize) {
        minIdle = maxPoolSize;
     }

     if (maxLifetime < 0) {
        logger.error("maxLifetime cannot be negative.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxLifetime cannot be negative.");
     }
     else if (maxLifetime > 0 && maxLifetime < TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(120)) {
        logger.warn("maxLifetime is less than 120000ms, using default {}ms.", MAX_LIFETIME);
        maxLifetime = MAX_LIFETIME;
     }

     if (idleTimeout != 0 && idleTimeout < TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30)) {
        logger.warn("idleTimeout is less than 30000ms, using default {}ms.", IDLE_TIMEOUT);
        idleTimeout = IDLE_TIMEOUT;
     }
     else if (idleTimeout > maxLifetime && maxLifetime > 0) {
        logger.warn("idleTimeout is greater than maxLifetime, setting to maxLifetime.");
        idleTimeout = maxLifetime;
     }
```

from this code, the maxLifeTime is at least 120000ms, using default 1800000ms. so you can't set the `maxLifeTime` to 30000ms(30*1000). I guess your `HikariCP` version is at least older than 2.2.4.

But when you find [the latest `HikariCP` version 2.7.4](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). it said "**We strongly recommend setting this value, and it should be at least 30 seconds less than any database or infrastructure imposed connection time limit.**"

the same class `HikariConfig.class`:

```
private void validateNumerics() {
    if(this.maxLifetime != 0L && this.maxLifetime < TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30L)) {
        LOGGER.warn("{} - maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, setting to default {}ms.", this.poolName, Long.valueOf(MAX_LIFETIME));
        this.maxLifetime = MAX_LIFETIME;
    }

    if(this.idleTimeout + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1L) > this.maxLifetime && this.maxLifetime > 0L) {
        LOGGER.warn("{} - idleTimeout is close to or more than maxLifetime, disabling it.", this.poolName);
        this.idleTimeout = 0L;
    }

    if(this.idleTimeout != 0L && this.idleTimeout < TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10L)) {
        LOGGER.warn("{} - idleTimeout is less than 10000ms, setting to default {}ms.", this.poolName, Long.valueOf(IDLE_TIMEOUT));
        this.idleTimeout = IDLE_TIMEOUT;
    }

    if(this.leakDetectionThreshold > 0L && !unitTest && (this.leakDetectionThreshold < TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2L) || this.leakDetectionThreshold > this.maxLifetime && this.maxLifetime > 0L)) {
        LOGGER.warn("{} - leakDetectionThreshold is less than 2000ms or more than maxLifetime, disabling it.", this.poolName);
        this.leakDetectionThreshold = 0L;
    }

    if(this.connectionTimeout < 250L) {
        LOGGER.warn("{} - connectionTimeout is less than 250ms, setting to {}ms.", this.poolName, Long.valueOf(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT));
        this.connectionTimeout = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
    }

    if(this.validationTimeout < 250L) {
        LOGGER.warn("{} - validationTimeout is less than 250ms, setting to {}ms.", this.poolName, Long.valueOf(VALIDATION_TIMEOUT));
        this.validationTimeout = VALIDATION_TIMEOUT;
    }

    if(this.maxPoolSize < 1) {
        this.maxPoolSize = this.minIdle <= 0?10:this.minIdle;
    }

    if(this.minIdle < 0 || this.minIdle > this.maxPoolSize) {
        this.minIdle = this.maxPoolSize;
    }

}
```

from this code, the `maxLifeTime` has been updated to 30000ms at least in this version.

So now please update your `HikariCP` version to the latest version 2.7.4 if you want to set maxLifeTime to 30000ms.

But if you update your HikariCP version to 2.7.4 with JDK 8, i also recommend you two points:

**1. to set `maxLifeTime` value to be at least 30000ms.**

**2. to set `maxLifeTime` value few minute less than mysql's `wait_timeout`(`show variables like "%timeout%"`) to avoid broken connection exception.**

Comment: I am using MSSQL. MSSQL is set to 600s or 600000ms by default. Then I set maxLifeTime == 600000 but still I get the error/warning: idleTimeout is close to or more than maxLifetime. Same thing if I set it less 30 seconds, 570000. The funny thing is that if I don't set this... just use the default value of 30 minutes the error will go away but I am not sure if that is a guarantee that there is no broken connection because its the other way around now.

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul what's version of your HikariCP?

Comment: HikariCP-2.7.9.jar and hibernate-hikaricp-5.2.17.Final.jar, I am not sure which of these because I am just let Spring Boot dependency do the version management. The springboot I am using is spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.0.5.RELEASE.

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul can you debug the HikariConfig.class?

Comment: I'd love to. But I don't have time right now, I'll check next week.

Comment: please see my answer above. It is an improvement to your answer :)! Cheers.

Comment: Postgres doesn't have wait_timeout.

PostgreSQL currently has:

"statement_timeout" - Abort any statement that takes more than the specified number of milliseconds, starting from the time the command arrives at the server from the client.
"idle_in_transaction_session_timeout" - Terminate any session with an open transaction that has been idle for longer than the specified duration in milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

Using Hikari version 2.7.9 and I made the following settings:

```
HikariConfig cpConfig = new HikariConfig();
cpConfig.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
cpConfig.setUsername(username);
cpConfig.setPassword(password);
cpConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(15);
cpConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");

// performance senstive settings
cpConfig.setMinimumIdle(0);
cpConfig.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
cpConfig.setIdleTimeout(35000);
cpConfig.setMaxLifetime(45000);

cpConfig.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

HikariDataSource cpDatasource = new HikariDataSource(cpConfig);
localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(cpDatasource);
localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
```

and it works.
But please be careful with:

```
 cpConfig.setMinimumIdle(0);
```

If your DB e.g. like MSSQL has infinite MaxLifetime this has to be set strictly to 0 or else you will have many connections not closed infinitely (indefinitely)


Cheers,
Artanis Zeratul

Comment: yes, the HikariCP configuration recommend not setting this value. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Comment: The ` cpConfig.setMinimumIdle(0);` helped me a lot.