# HikariCP: MariaDB stops retrieving connections after ~5 minutes of idling

Tags: java, mariadb, connection-pooling, hikaricp, connection-timeout

I've created a simple program that connects to the MariaDB database using HikariCP (connection pooling, https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). Everything works fine as long as the connection doesn't idle for more than like 5 minutes. After 5 minutes of idling all the queries will fail and the following error will be thrown:

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@2b6d3853 (Connection.setNetworkTimeout cannot be called on a closed connection). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30025ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:697)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:196)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:161)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
    at net.cubeverse.cvdiscordbot.database.Database.getConnection(Database.java:45)
    at net.cubeverse.cvdiscordbot.database.DiscordVerifyDAO.isVerified(DiscordVerifyDAO.java:81)
    at net.cubeverse.cvdiscordbot.command.discord.VerifyCommand.execute(VerifyCommand.java:25)
    at net.cubeverse.cvdiscordbot.core.command.manager.CommandManager.executeDiscordCommand(CommandManager.java:34)
    at net.cubeverse.cvdiscordbot.listeners.MessageListeners.onPrivateMessageReceived(MessageListeners.java:21)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:397)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:84)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:111)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:37)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:868)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:766)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:745)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:903)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:368)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:270)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:990)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:749)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection.setNetworkTimeout cannot be called on a closed connection
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getSqlException(ExceptionMapper.java:277)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.setNetworkTimeout(MariaDbConnection.java:1700)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setNetworkTimeout(PoolBase.java:552)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:168)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:185)
    ... 22 more
```

**Code (connecting to the database and retrieving connection)**
I establish the connection with the following code and return it via #getConnection(). I've tried experimenting around with maxLifetime, but I couldn't solve the issue. I've also checked MySQL timeout settings to make sure maxLifetime connection is shorter than wait_timeout.

```
public class Database {

    private final HikariDataSource hikari;

    public Database() {
        // Setting up the hikari config
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://ip:port/database");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("xxxxx");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("xxxxx");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("useLocalSessionState", "true");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("rewriteBatchedStatements", "true");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("cacheResultSetMetadata", "true");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("cacheServerConfiguration", "true");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("elideSetAutoCommits", "true");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("maintainTimeStats", "false");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("maxLifetime", "600000");
        // Source: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration

        // Initialize a new hikari object
        hikari = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            System.out.println(S.INFO.getPrefix() + "Successfully established the database connection.");
            return hikari.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(S.ERROR.getPrefix() + "Failed to establish the database connection.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Timeout settings**
I'm running the default timeout settings:

```
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout            | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout          | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout           | 30       |
| net_write_timeout          | 60       |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600     |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout   | 60       |
| wait_timeout               | 28800    |
+----------------------------+----------+
```

**Environment**

```
JDK version : 1.8.0_111
Database : 5.5.60-MariaDB
Driver version : 2.4.2 (org.mariadb.jdbc.mariadb-java-client)
OS: : Linux CentOS 7
```

I've also opened an issue on HikariCP's repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1403)

Comment: Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694402/2834978): `maxLifetime < wait_timeout (mysql)`.

Comment: maxLifetime is given in miliseconds 600000 -> 600 seconds, while wait_timeout is  given in seconds 28800. That means wait_timeout is higher than maxLifetime.

Comment: The error says "Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value." I've also experimented with settings extremely low maxLifetime value but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Try removing it and using the default.

Comment: I've tried removing it and running default, still the same error. + I've tried running all default HikariCP's settings.

Comment: "maxLifetime is given in miliseconds 600000 -> 600 seconds, while wait_timeout is given in seconds 28800. That means wait_timeout is higher than maxLifetime". Actually maxLifeTime is in ms and wait_timeout in seconds, so it's lower.